# Image collage on tkinter - for loop code issue

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am learning tkinter images and I trying to show 3 images one after the other in tkinter gui. i did it with the below code and now i am trying to use for loop rather than coding for each image but I am not able to. please help me

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import os
root = Tk()

#WidthxHeight
root.geometry('733x434')
files = os.listdir('Images')
image_list =[]


for file in files:
        image_list.append(file)


image = Image.open(f'Images/{image_list[0]}')
photo1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
Label(image=photo1).pack()

image = Image.open(f'Images/{image_list[1]}')
photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
Label(image=photo2).pack()

image = Image.open(f'Images/{image_list[2]}')
photo3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
Label(image=photo3).pack()


#for i in range(len(image_list)):
#       photo = []
#       image = Image.open(f'Images/{image_list[i]}')
#       photo[i] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
#       Label(image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for loop as long as you keep those references of images, otherwise they will be garbage collected:

```py
for file in image_list:
    image = Image.open(f'Images/{file}')
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    # the above two lines can be replaced by
    # photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=f'Images/{file}')
    lbl = Label(root, image=photo)
    lbl.pack()
    # use an attribute of the label to store the reference of the image
    # to avoid garbage collection
    lbl.image = photo
```

Comment: Thank You !!! The code is working. As a new learner do I always have to create a label attribute and then pack it separately. I usually directly create Label and pack it in single line. I dont want to form a bad habit so asking :D

Answer (score 0):

> Image collage on tkinter

You don't need looping.

Commented out 8, 9, 12 and 13.

Replace this:

```
image = Image.open(f'Images/{image_list[0]}')
```

with:

```
image = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Supra\Documents\python3_dummy\tmp_dummy\temp-Dummy\p1.png')
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! The code looks super simple but it is not working for me(Permission Denied). I have opened my pycharm in a folder having Images folder and in Images folder I have 3 images.
This is what I did -

from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import os
root = Tk()

#WidthxHeight
root.geometry('733x434')

image = Image.open(r'Images')

root.mainloop()


I dont see how this code will work without a loop because I think I need to specify image name with .jpg.